# How to add a line using h1:after after a h1 element with padding

Tags: html, css

When I try to create a h1 element with padding and set it as an inline then follow up with a screen wide line using h1:after it ends up with the padding of the h1 element on a new line, how can I get the paddin of the h1 element to be before the horizontal line?

The css code is as follows.

```
h1 {
    font-size: 15px;    
    background: #ccc;
    display: inline;
    padding: 8px 0px 5px 10px;
}


.headline {
    font-family: Calibri, "Helvetica", san-serif;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
}

h1:after {
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    border:4px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:1px;
    -webkit-border-radius:1px;
    -moz-border-radius:1px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

And the html code is simply a span with class headline inside a h1 element.

It currently looks like this:
[image: How it looks now]
And I want it to look pretty much the same except that the padding that gets put below the line at the end of the text.

Comment: I added a picture showing how it looks and a description of how I want i to look.

Comment: Thank you so much! Been at this way longer than I dare say ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overthinking the issue.

Leave the `h1` as a block level item and move the styles around to the `span`.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.headline {
  font-family: Calibri, "Helvetica", san-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 8px 10px 3px 10px;
}

h1 {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="headline">Headline</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
h1 display:-webkit-inline-box; or inline-flex;